# python, shuffle a array of list in a specifiic range?

Tags: python, list, shuffle

i want to ask if i got a array of list in python like this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

How do i shuffle within range `a[1][1]` to `a[1][4]`?

I only know the normal shuffle

```
random.shuffle(a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a sample from the sublist, with the sample size set to the same length, then assign that sample back to the slice:

```
a[1][1:4] = random.sample(a[1][1:4], 3)
```

This takes a sample of the 3 elements from the source list (producing those same 3 elements in random order), and assigns these right back to the same indices.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very easy way!

Answer (score 1):

For reference, in case you want to use `shuffle` you can follow the same approach given by Martijn, but it requires to assign the slice to a name, since shuffle mixes things in place

```
>>> s=a[1][1:4]
>>> s
[2, 3, 4]
>>> shuffle(s)
>>> s
[4, 2, 3]
>>> a[1][1:4] = s
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank you too! Its more useful to use the "s" for a[1][1:4]